# How to effectively explain casual research assistance projects on CV

Tags: publications, cv, research-assistantship

Recently, alongside my day job (high school teacher), I have been taking up casual short-term research assistant jobs - these are not only paid, but also include me being a co-author of the paper(s) that result.

On my CV, I would like to have all this information, what would be an effective means to include all achievements of these projects?

I am hoping for specific examples if people have done this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to answer your question, you need to first understand *who your CV is written for*. If your CV is for you, and you are simply trying to document what you did, then you can simply list each research involvement as something like:

- **January 2014--July 2014** Research volunteer, Dr. Bigwig's lab. Collected samples from subjects and ran computer simulations. Contributed to 5 publications.

Ideally, you will also be able to list the publications to which you contribute.

If you are building the CV because you want to actually use it for something (getting a raise, getting another job, going back to school, etc.), then you should seek to formalize your relationship with the lab:

- Do you have a title? If not, ask for one. Since you say you are being paid, you probably have one already. You should know the title and list it.
- List the dates of the appointment. Typically they are for a year or a few years, even if you are only being paid for a small fraction of that.
- Since you are currently a high school teacher, you may wish to list your research appointments in a different section of your CV than your teaching appointments.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

1. Detail the employer and your role, make clear that your work was part-time or casual.
2. Indicate that you contributed to a number of reports, perhaps even citing the number of reports that you contributed to.
3. Make a specific reference to any reports that are appropriate to the job you're applying for.

Answer (score 2):

For HR specialists reading your CV there will be important not just employment history, but also another perspectives of your CV.

1. a project history you have done or participated, then they need to know short one simple sentence of project description and your role on the project.
2. publications you have made or co-author.

If this is significant enough, put this to the Overview, what should be on the front page of your CV. Overview generally should contain teasers for the rest of CV. How many projects, how many publications, etc.

Take an example of different perspectives for example from Linked-in portal, which are: Overview, Employment history, Project history, Personal initiatives, language skills, Certifications, Courses, Skills, Education, Recommendations, Publications, Organization membership, Prizes, Academical Results, Patents, etc. Order is up to your priorities.

Example: So, I can imagine you could have Overview, Education, Project history, Academical results and Publications in top order.